# Datagrid rows are blank

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My datagrid is giving me the correct amount of rows but there is no data in the rows.

Here is my WPF code

```
<Grid AllowDrop="True">
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="c1" Header="Full Name" Binding="{Binding FullNames}" Width="200"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="c2" Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Ages}" Width="200"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="128,296,0,3" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is my code behind

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string FullNames { get; set; }
    public int Ages { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGrid.DataContext = GetInfo();

    }


    private List<string> GetInfo()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        List<int> listAge = new List<int>();

        list.Add(FullNames = "User 1" );
        list.Add(FullNames = "User 2");
        list.Add(FullNames = "User 3");
        list.Add(FullNames = "User 4");
        list.Add(FullNames = "User 5");
        listAge.Add(Ages = 35);
        listAge.Add(Ages = 34);
        listAge.Add(Ages = 10);
        listAge.Add(Ages = 8);
        listAge.Add(Ages = 4);

        return list;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.  By the way, I have to write this because stackoverflow is saying that I need more detail.  I thought the little I wrote and code was sufficient, but I guess not, lol

Answer (score 0):

The UI isn't getting updated when those properties are assigned to, to update the UI:
1) use an ObservableCollection, this is a list that updates the UI when items are added or removed from it.
2) define a class such as:

```
public class Person: DependencyObject
{

    public string name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(nameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(nameProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for name.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty nameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("name", typeof(string), typeof(Person), new PropertyMetadata("Fred"));


    public int age
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ageProperty, value);
            if (fireshower != null)
                fireshower.Value = value;
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for age.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("age", typeof(int), typeof(RuleTileInfo), new PropertyMetadata(0));


}
```

This does 2 things for you: It will make your code more easily extendable now that information is neatly organized, and if a persons age is changed the UI will receive an update about that.
3) while it's okay to set the datacontext to the Observable collection and use ItemsSource={Binding}, it's better practice to place all objects that are shown in your UI into a view model and set the datacontext of your window to the view model. then bind to the name of the list in that view model. A VM for thsi case might be:

```
public class WindowVM: DependencyObject
{

public ObservableCollection<Person> People
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(PeepleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PeopleProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for name.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
//ect

}
```

This will help organize your program and make it both easier to understand and more maintainable. tip: Dependancy properties are cumbersome to type out by hand, use the snippet for them (type propdp and hit tab twice, fill out the fields hitting tab to switch between them and VS will fill in the redundant info for you)

Comment: Thank you for your input!! Sorry for getting back so late.   Dependency Properties are a little over my head.  I'm really just trying to understand binding in WPF.  Thanks again